# Concatenating substring?

Tags: c, string

i would like to find out how i could concatenate substrings.

For Example, if i was given the word **xyz** i would like my output to be **xxyxyz**

I have tried writing my code using Strncat , basically i have would like to extract substrings and concatenate it into the output.

How do i 'pull out' substrings from a string generated from user input and be able to input it into string format for C?

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <string.h>

int main()
{
char str[100];
int i;

printf("Enter Word :" );
scanf("%s",str);

for(i=0;i<strlength(str);i++){
strncat(str(i),str(i++),i++)
}

printf("conc : %s" , str);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is `str(i)`? `str` is an array, not a function.

Comment: True but i can't seem to find a workaround to manipulate the string

Comment: use square brackets for indexing a string

Comment: While you can do this using the same variable, it will take longer to execute and is more complex since you need to swap the original string with the generated substrings. Also, it means you have a smaller limit on the number of characters you may accept. More precisely, it must satisfy the condition `L >= sum(0..n)`, where `L` is the length of the buffer, `n` is the number of characters read (inclusive), and `sum(0..n)` adds all integers from 0 to `n`. For example, 13 would be the maximum here because `sum(0..14) = 105`, which is greater than 100, and `sum(0..13)=91`, which is less than 100.

Comment: @EonTea If you ever have a question about the correct name for a function in `string.h` (or any header), just `man string.h` and you are provided a concise listing. That will help you avoid problems like `strlength`. Also remember to compile with `-Wall -Wextra` to enable  warnings and *read* and eliminate *all* warnings before attempting to execute your code. All of your code should compile with *zero* warnings at this stage of your learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate variable for the result string, instead of concatenating to the same string you're starting with. Initialize it to an empty string, then use `strncat` to concatenate the substrings to it.

To get a substring, use `strncpy()`.

```
char input[100];
char output[5000] = "";
size_t i;

printf("Enter word: ");
scanf("%s", input);

size_t len = strlen(input);

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    strncat(output, input, i);
}

printf("conc: %s\n", output);
```

Comment: `scanf("%99s", input);`

Answer (score 0):

we can concatenate substring in different ways

one way is like you with small modifications(by allocating memory dynamically and other way using arrays)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str;
    int i, len;

    str = (char *) malloc(100);
    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    len = strlen(str);

    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++)
    {
        strncat(str, str, i);
    }

    strcpy(str,str+len);
    printf("conc: %s\n", str);

return 0;
} // main
```

or

```
int main()
{
    char str[100]           ={0};
    char ResultString[100]  ={0};
    int i, len;

    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    len = strlen(str);

    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++)
    {
        strncat(ResultString, str, i);
    } 

    printf("conc: %s\n", ResultString);

return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: interesting, i'm brand new in C but i can definetely appreciate the approach of solving C from people who are much better and experince. Thanks alot for the help!